# Does the EDI Tradacoms standard provide a test flag?

Tags: biztalk, edi, tradacoms

I'm currently looking into coding a B2B/EDI integration, using the TRADACOMS standard, for integration with a UK-based company. I have lots of experience with EDIFACT, however TRADACOMS is very new to me.

In EDIFACT (EU-based) there is something called a test flag (UNB11).
In X12 (US-based), there is ISA15 (I/T/P).

Is there a similar field in the TRADACOMS spec to use? I have received some information on TRADACOMS standards, but can't seem to grasp any mentioning of this field.
If no such thing is present within the standard, then how would this typically be done?

Comment: No, tradacoms does not have a tst flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no explicit Test/Production flag as there is with X12 or EDIFACT.

This requirement can be met by simply using different Application Codes for each purpose.